# Moving the derivative under the integral of a convolution

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have functions $f(x)$ and $g(t,x)$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^d; t \in \mathbb{R}$. I further assume that these functions fall off fast enough for $|x| \rightarrow \infty$. I want to show the following equality:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} (f(x) * \partial_t g(t,x) ) g(t,x) dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} (f(x) * g(t,x) ) \partial_tg(t,x) dx.$$
However, I'm not sure what properties of the convolution product I have to use to show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \big(f(\cdot)*\partial_t g(t,\cdot)\big)(x)g(t,x)dx = \big\langle (f(\cdot)*\partial_t g(t,\cdot))(x),g(t,x)\big\rangle$$ $$= \left\langle \widehat{f(\cdot)*\partial_t g(t,\cdot)}(\xi),\widehat{g(t,\cdot)}(\xi)\right\rangle = \left\langle \widehat{f(\cdot)}(\xi)\widehat{\partial_t g(t,\cdot)}(\xi),\widehat{g(t,\cdot)}(\xi)\right\rangle$$ $$= \left\langle \widehat{f(\cdot)}(\xi)\widehat{g(t,\cdot)}(\xi),\widehat{\partial_t g(t,\cdot)}(\xi)\right\rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \big(f(\cdot)*g(t,\cdot)\big)(x)\partial_t g(t,x)dt$$

Comment: I assume $\hat{f}$ denotes the Fourier transform of $f$ ? Then, could you elaborate on why the penultimate step is justified?

Comment: @JoeWolf $\langle ab,c\rangle = \int (ab)c = \int (ac)b = \langle ac,b \rangle$

Comment: I wonder why this answer was accepted, the proof is still false, since it seems to be using the identity
$$
\langle u,v\rangle = \langle \mathcal{F}(u),\mathcal{F}(v)\rangle
$$
while it should be
$$
\langle u,v\rangle = \langle \mathcal{F}(u),\mathcal{F}^{-1}(v)\rangle.
$$

Comment: @LL3.14 what does "still" mean?

Comment: That I indicated it one month ago in my post. I don't know if there were corrections since then but it is still false. It would be good to delete it or to precise it.

Comment: @LL3.14 you can see that nothing has been edited recently

Comment: So it should be indicated false, edited or deleted, it might be misleading for readers.

Answer (score 0):

It is false in general. **If $f$ or $g$ is an even function of $x$**, then it is true. You can just use the definition of the convolution and Fubini theorem to get
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} (f*\partial_tg(t,\cdot))(x)\, g(t,x)\,\mathrm{d} x &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x-y)\,\partial_tg(t,y)\,\mathrm{d}y\right) g(t,x)\,\mathrm{d} x
\\
&= \iint_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x-y)\,\partial_tg(t,y)\, g(t,x)\,\mathrm{d} x \,\mathrm{d}y
\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x-y)\,g(t,x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right) \partial_tg(t,y)\,\mathrm{d} y
\end{align*}
$$

- And now if $f$ is even then $f(x-y) = f(y-x)$, and you get
  $$
  \begin{align*}
  \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(y-x)\,g(t,x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right) \partial_tg(t,y)\,\mathrm{d} y &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x-y)\,g(t,x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right) \partial_tg(t,y)\,\mathrm{d} y
  \\
  &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} (f*g(t,\cdot))(x)\, \partial_tg(t,x)\,\mathrm{d} x
  \end{align*}
  $$
- If $g$ is even then you can do the changes of variables replacing $x$ by $-x$ and $y$ by $-y$, which will not change $g$ and $\partial_t g$ but will replace $f(x-y)$ by $f(y-x)$ so you get the same result.

And for it to be valid, you should either have positive functions, or check that the double integral $\iint_{\mathbb{R}^d} |f(x-y)\,\partial_tg(t,y)\, g(t,x)|\,\mathrm{d} x \,\mathrm{d}y$ is finite, or use distribution theory.

---

To understand why it is false in the general case, we can for example take $f = \delta_1$ in dimension $d=1$  to simplify (but you could also take a $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$ function with support in a very small ball centered around some unit vector). Then your equality would lead to
$$
\begin{align*}
∫_{\mathbb{R}^d} \partial_t g(x-1)\, g(x)\,\mathrm{d} x &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} g(x-1)\, \partial_tg(x)\,\mathrm{d} x
\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \partial_tg(x+1)\,g(x)\,\mathrm{d} x
\end{align*}
$$
which is false in general (take for example at some time $t$, $g$ positive compactly supported in $[-1/2,1/2]$ and $\partial_t g$ positive compactly supported in $[1/2,3/2]$, then the first integral is positive but the second is $0$.

---

You can also prove it with the Fourier transform, as done by Mathworker, but his proof is false since there should be a minus sign appearing somewhere. For example
$$
\begin{align*}
∫_{\mathbb{R}^d} (f*\partial_t g)(x)\, g(x)\,\mathrm{d} x &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \widehat{f*\partial_t g}(x)\, \widehat{g}(-x)\,\mathrm{d} x
\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \widehat{f}(x)\,\partial_t \widehat{g}(x)\, \widehat{g}(-x)\,\mathrm{d} x
\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \widehat{f}(-x)\,\partial_t \widehat{g}(-x)\, \widehat{g}(x)\,\mathrm{d} x
\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \widehat{\check{f}*g}(x)\, \widehat{\partial_tg}(-x)\,\mathrm{d} x
\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \check{f}*g(x)\, \partial_tg(x)\,\mathrm{d} x
\end{align*}
$$
where $\check{f}(x) = f(-x)$.

Comment: Hence why I said you should start off by saying "not an answer"

Comment: Okok, I added a counterexample.

Comment: OP said functions. Also, I am indeed a male.